# Magento Change the Invoice Number format

Tags: magento

Currently, the invoice no. is XXXXXXX. I need to change it the format YYYY-MM-XXXX

YYYY - current year
MM  - Current month
XXXX - autogenerated no. starting with 1900 in the beginning of every month.

I saw many posts which talk about changing the increment value or adding a character such as INV to the invoice no.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Note: Backup your database before you proceed.

Here is basic understanding:
**eav_entity_store** table has two options of interest: **1)increment_prefix** and **2)increment_last_id**. 
**increment_prefix** specifies which prefix will be added to number and by default equals «1». 
**increment_last_id** defines the last entity number.

Here we can change the starting number of orders, invoices and shipments. 
**eav_entity_type** table has settings which allow us to change the number format. These are **increment_pad_length** which is used to set the length of the number excluding its prefix and **increment_pad_char** used to specify the character used to pad the number to required length. By default it is zero. Another important field is **increment_model** which specifies the class that is used to generate numbers.

Overwrite **Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Order** in folder **app/code/local/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Increment** with the following content:

```
class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Order extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Abstract
{
    public function getNextId()
    {
        $last = $this->getLastId();

        if (strpos($last, $this->getPrefix()) === 0) {
            $last = (int)substr($last, strlen($this->getPrefix()) + 2);
        } else {
            $last = (int)$last;
        }

        $next = $last+1;

        return $this->format($next);
    }

    public function format($id)
    {
        $result  = $this->getPrefix() . date('y'); //year is appended to the increment id
        $result .= str_pad((string)$id, $this->getPadLength(), $this->getPadChar(), STR_PAD_LEFT);
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Modify the code as per your needs.

Source: [atwix](http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-order-and-customer-numbers/)